# OnClick = method simulate is meant to be run 1 one = 0 found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

Unable to figure out the following error:     Using Jest Enzyme -  React JS

**   Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
**

I am trying to test onClick = for props/properties . onClick is called a couple times for this file. I tried to apply the same method that I used for a different file but its not working at the moment 
Example :
onClick calling ( this.props) :

```
   <div className="continue_button_div">
  <button className='cancel_button' id='cancel-add-new-view' 
  title='Cancel' type='button' onClick={() => 
 {this.props.hideAddViewModal()}}>Cancel</button>
  </div>

 <div className="continue_button_div">
 <button className='cancel_button' id='cancel-add-new-view' title='Cancel' 
 type='button' onClick={() => 
 {this.props.hideAddViewModal()}}>Cancel</button>
```

I did the following for my test files.

```
// jest mock functions (mocks this.props.func)
const hideAddViewModal =  jest.fn();
// defining this.props
const baseProps = {
hideAddViewModal,

describe('AddViewModal Test', () => {
let wrapper;
let tree;

beforeEach(() => wrapper = shallow(<AddViewModal {...baseProps} />));

   it("should call hideAddViewModal functions on button click", () => {
// Reset info from possible previous calls of these mock functions:
baseProps.hideAddViewModal.mockClear();
wrapper.setProps({
});
// Find the button and call the onClick handler
wrapper.find('.sidemodal_addnew_x').at(0).simulate("click"); //pass
wrapper.find('.cancel_button').at(0).simulate("click"); //fails
wrapper.find('.cancel_button').at(1).simulate("click");//fails
```

But i keep getting the error described on top.

Another onClick example. Could I apply the method above the same for this one as well or how could I make sure onClick calls clearviewName = () = {

```
clearViewName = () => {

this.setState({ViewName: ''});
this.setState({Requests: ''});
this.setState({allowNext: false})

Render(){
 <div className="fullmodal_title_select"><span 
className="fullmodal_title_add_done" onClick={() => {this.clearViewName()}} 
>Add View  </span><FontAwesome name='right' className='fa-angle-right' />  
Select a request</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are there up to 5 elements with the class `.sidemodal_addnew_x` ?
`wrapper.find('.sidemodal_addnew_x').at(4).simulate("click");` implies there are
I make an assumption that there's only 1.
therefore this:
`wrapper.find('.sidemodal_addnew_x').at(0).simulate("click");`
May work

Comment: @delis theres only one - 0 doesn't work, I keep getting the same error

Comment: what happens when you find it by it's id instead
`wrapper.find('close-add-view-modal').simulate("click");`

also is it possible to change this:
`beforeEach(() => wrapper = shallow(<BrowserRouter><AddViewModal {...baseProps} /></BrowserRouter>));`

to 
`beforeEach(() => wrapper = shallow(<AddViewModal {...baseProps} />));`

I have this feeling that `shallow(<BrowserRouter><AddViewModal {...baseProps} /></BrowserRouter>)`

Just doesn't render `AddViewModal` component at all

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried both options above. I even changed the main file, which I'm not supposed to.

Comment: Actually i Removed the BrowserRouter and Tried to run the file : found a mistake :     expect(baseProps.hideAddViewModall).toHaveBeenCalled(); =  spelled Modal wrong - included 2 L's. The test runs. But hideViewModal is being used 2 other times for a classname 'cancel_button' . How could I call at it

Comment: So that's a positive in a way (it's getting past the first stage). 
-------This: `But hideViewModal is being used 2 other times for a classname 'cancel_button' . How could I call at it `------ Could you explain further what you mean............if you want to test it you could do something similar to what you have up `wrapper.find('.cancel_button').at(0).simulate("click");` , `wrapper.find('.cancel_button').at(1).simulate("click");`

Comment: I edited my code to make easier to understand  -  I tried to apply the same method with cancel but did not work .

Comment: I see, can you still add more of your code?

is it possible that the cancel components are only conditionally displayed?

Comment: what file should is this at?

Comment: addview - under components

Comment: aii...Would look at it

Comment: Any updates? still working on it

Comment: I'm back....so basically as I thought, both components containing `cancel_button` would only render if some certain states meet certain criteria...

Comment: You can call `wrapper.setState` just before simulating click on those components
I'd write a possible solution in the answer...it's hard formatting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically something like this:

```
it('For first cancel button', () => {
        // Reset info from possible previous calls of these mock functions:
        baseProps.hideAddViewModal.mockClear();
        wrapper.setProps({});
        // Find the button and call the onClick handler
        wrapper.setState({
          ViewName: 'something',
          allowNext: true,
        })
        wrapper.find('.cancel_button').at(0).simulate('click');
})
```

then

```
it('For second cancel button', () => {
        // Reset info from possible previous calls of these mock functions:
        baseProps.hideAddViewModal.mockClear();
        wrapper.setProps({});
        // Find the button and call the onClick handler
        wrapper.setState({
          ViewName: 'something',
          RequestID: 'something',
          Requests: ['random, I dont know the type inside here so']
        })
        wrapper.find('.cancel_button').at(0).simulate('click');
})
```

Also is there any reason why you write your click handlers like this

```
onClick={() => {
  this.onContinueClick();
}}
```

instead of this

```
onClick={this.onContinueClick}
```

About the other issue,

You can edit `baseProps` to look like this:

```
const baseProps = {
   hideAddViewModal,
   location: {
     pathname: 'home'
   },
}
```

Comment: Delis thanks, but new error showed up Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined on line 252 annd 268

Comment: alright...I'd look at that too sorry was offline for a bit

Comment: Delis. Thank you. I was able to figure out later in the day as well.

Comment: delis : could I use the same method for the following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770134/how-could-i-test-onclick-for-multiple-events-jest-enzyme

Comment: @user9191 would take a look.....But generally you can use similar method